# How do I login to a network which requires authentication in Metasploitable

Tags: linux, networking, authentication, metasploit

I am running *Linux metasploitable 2.6.24-16-server* on VirtualBox. I want to connect to the internet but my network requires authentication for which I usually login using a browser. But, since metasploitable does not have any GUI, I don't seem to be able to connect to the internet.

Can anyone suggest me to overcome this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Metasploitable is a VM that is especially designed to be hackable. Using it to surf the internet seems like a bad idea. Why do you need this?

Comment: Thanks for the response! @Panki
Indeed you are right, but I wanted to connect to the internet because I wanted to update my Metasploitable machine and install a few packages that aren't already installed.